# How to chain observables in rxjava2

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have two observables in my code. The first one is a merged observable for search button click and text change.

```
Observable<String> buttonClickStream = createButtonClickObservable();
Observable<String> textChangeStream = createTextChangeObservable();
Observable<String> searchTextObservable 
    =Observable.merge(buttonClickStream,textChangeStream);

disposable = searchTextObservable
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnNext(s -> showProgressBar())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .map(this::getStarredRepos)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(gitHubRepos -> {
        hideProgressBar();
        showResults(gitHubRepos);
    });
```

The second observable is for getting response from server.:

```
private List<GitHubRepo> getStarredRepos(String username) {
    RestInterface restService=RestService
       .getClient().create(RestInterface.class);
    restService.getStarredRepos(username)
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .subscribe(this::handleResponse, this::handleError);

    return repoList;
}
```

Now the problem is, hideProgressBar() and showResults() methods are executing before handleResponse() finishes.

I am new to RxJava, so if there is anything wrong in code please rectify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `List<GitHubRepo> getStarredRepos(...)` should instead be `Observable<List<GitHubRepo>> getStarredRepos(...)`. Don't subscribe to the observable inside of this method, but return the observable you get from restService (if you need to process the response, put a `map()` before returning, for errors you can use `onErrorReturn()` or something you need).

Then instead of `.map(this::getStarredRepos)` do `.switchMap(this::getStarredRepos)`.